# Qlikview URL parameter selection not working due to cache

Tags: qlikview

I am trying to embed a Qlikview chart in a custom webpage via an iframe - using singleobject.htm. I want to apply a certain filter so i am passing "&select=LB186,CSP" where LB186 is the listbox in the actual qlikview document.

This "select" paramater in the URL doesnt seem to work because of caching. I also tried to replace LB186 by the actual field name, that did not work either.

I want to somehow clear cache and load the page as a fresh reload. appending a random var=XXX hack also doesn't work. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to use bookmark instead
2. alternative url below, please remember that here document part is url encoded:

```
https://$servername/qvajaxzfc/authenticate.aspx?type=html&try=/qvajaxzfc/singleobject.htm?document=example.qvw%26object%3DDocument\CH1&back=/LoginPage.htm&webticket=$ticket
```

Comment: no even bookmark did not work. Page was still coming cached. Also encoded URL not working